# VC++ Charts using Chart X

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, com, class-library

I'm new to drawing  the chart  using chartfx

can you give me the meanings of teh following methods,
they are kinda confusing...I did not find documentation anywhere.

GetValue ( )
GetXValue ( )
PutItem()

Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 1):

When you download the library, you will get atleast a basic documentation for the APIs. This documentation is also available for the trial version of the library. The paid version will have online support as well.

AFAIR, GetXValue() -- will return the value of the x-coordinate at the specified index(argument). I.e if you want the x-coordinate of the 3rd point on the graph/plot you will call GetXValue(3).

For the other APIs and examples you can refer [support.softwarefx.com](http://support.softwarefx.com) which has details.